# Can't execute viewController from UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

Tags: ios, objective-c

First of all, apologize for my english.
I'm a beginner in iOS development, I'm doing an App which have 3 `viewControllers` (MainViewController, CenterViewController and ActionViewController).

In a first VC (`MainVC`) I have a button, this button takes you to the CenterVC using `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`.

In a second VC (`CenterVC`) I have and other button that takes you to the `ActionVC`, but here is a problem. I can see the `ActionVC` but this VC is presented bellow `MainVC` with the Curl effect.

I have tried to solve using this code inside of the IBAction in a CenterVC:

```
- (IBAction)actionReveal:(id)sender {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
     ActionViewController *actionVC = [[ActionViewController      alloc]initWithNibName:@"ActionViewController" bundle:nil];
          [self presentViewController:actionVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
     }];
}
```

Please, anyone can help me with the problem?

Comment: It may be helps you     [self presentModalViewController:actionVC  animated:YES];

Comment: why your not using navigationcontroller for this....?

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? Present the view modally or navigate to the next view...

Comment: @Virussmca what's different by using Navigation...?

Comment: Hy everybody, I want use the curl effect to show two textFields and finally you'll click a join button, in the CenterViewController, that takes you to the ActionViewController. Finally, I want change the view when I'll make click in the CenterVC button. Please help me! I don't know How I can solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this using navigation controller :

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    //put this instance to navigation controller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailController animated:NO];
    // Animate the navigation controller
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    // Set animation time
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.01];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    // Commit animation
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: ios4+ UIView Animation Deprecated now apple suggest to use Block wise Animation

Comment: Thanks for the answer Samkit but, Nitin say that this method is deprecated... some other solution? please

Comment: Where I insert this code? I'm confuse... I insert the code inside the IBAction of CenterVC button? Is necessary create a navigation controller? Sorry but I'm a beginner... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Write the solution here in case anyone has had the same problem.

mainVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OXDcurlViewController.h"

@interface OXDmainViewController : UIViewController <OXDcurlViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *curlButton;

- (IBAction)curlReveal:(id)sender;

@end
```

mainVC.m:

```
#import "OXDmainViewController.h"
#import "OXDcurlViewController.h"
#import "OXDsecondViewController.h"

@interface OXDmainViewController ()

@end

@implementation OXDmainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)curlReveal:(id)sender {
    OXDcurlViewController *curlVC = [[OXDcurlViewController          alloc]initWithNibName:@"OXDcurlViewController" bundle:nil];
    curlVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    curlVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:curlVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
}

-(void)presentSecondVC{
    OXDsecondViewController *secondVC = [[OXDsecondViewController     alloc]initWithNibName:@"OXDsecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:^{}];

}



@end
```

curlVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol OXDcurlViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)presentSecondVC;

@end


@interface OXDcurlViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *actionButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<OXDcurlViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)actionReveal:(id)sender;


@end
```

curlVC.m:

```
#import "OXDcurlViewController.h"
#import "OXDsecondViewController.h"

@interface OXDcurlViewController ()
@end

@implementation OXDcurlViewController
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionReveal:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.delegate presentSecondVC];
    }];

}


@end
```

Thanks to all who have helped me.

David Álvarez Medina